# android emulators for xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble getting any android emulator other than "Xamarin Android Player" to work (only with older versions of android).

What kind of virtual device/settings/properties should I use so that I can test newer versions of android and not have to wait 15 minutes for the emulator to startup?

is there a "Go-to" virtual device/emulator setup that doesn't take 15+ minutes to load?

(using windows 10/Visual Studio 17/2015)

Comment: XAP is no longer supported.  Try Google's stock emulators, VS Emulator, Genymotion

Comment: Android Accel-x86-based emulators are Qemu & Intel HAXM based and are highly CPU (+ RAM & GPU) dependent in order to be performant. While Xamarin Android Player (XAM) and GenyMotion are Oracle VirtualBox based and run well on older hardware, XAM is depreciated and GenyMotion is a commercial ($) project. On newer hardware Android Accel-x86-based emulators startup times are typically equal (or faster) then a physical ARM-based device startup time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xamarin android player has been discontinued for a while. As a visual studio user you should probably be moving onto the Visual Studio Android Emulator. There is a guide here on setup

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/

it is also available with visual studio 2017, and if i remember correctly is an option available in the Vs2017 installer.

Comment: I'm having trouble installing because even though my hyper-v is enabled, it says my system doesn't have it!?

Comment: VS Emulators dont support android 7 and higher

Comment: link redirects to 404.

Comment: Link changed as previous went to 404

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest Genymotion for most uses. You can download the free version which works well for most basic things (there are also a few small things you can do using the `adb` command prompt without having to buy the full version, such as taking screenshots).

[Link to free version](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)

They have a good list of different devices. I have also recently even got it successfully connecting to my Parallels Windows machine while the emulator is running on my Mac. Let me know if you need help with this specific scenario.

The other option for you is the [Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/). When it first cam out I tried using it but was not able to because I would need to run it on a Parallels VM which does not allow nested virtualization.

Comment: VS Emulators dont have andorid 7 and higher otherwise, they are best emulators that are closer to real devices in my experience